# Configuring Nginx for multiple php sites on windows

Tags: php, nginx, web, configuration

I am a web developer and I build websites. But I have the following problem:

Since I can work from home (like probably most of us devs can do), I want to use nginx with php to continue working on websites. At work, one of my colleagues gave me **one nginx configuration** file which can serve **multiple sites**. I will post the whole code block below.

The problem is that I am working on windows 10 and I do not know how to make this code work on my machine.

My php version is **PHP 7.3.12** which is located under **C:\php**.

My nginx version is **1.16.1** which is located under **C:\nginx-1.16.1**.

I appreciate every help I can get!

```
server {

index index.php index.html index.htm;
set $basepath "/home/nik/Code/";

set $domain $host;

set $dynroot "/var/www";

# check multi name domain to multi application
if ($domain ~ "^(.*)\.(.[^.]*)\.(site|vpnsite)$") {
        set $customer $1;
        set $developer $2;
        set $rootpath "${developer}/${customer}/";
        set $servername "${customer}.${developer}.site";

        set $dynroot "$basepath/$rootpath";
}

if ($domain ~ "^(.*)\.(.[^.]*)\.laravel$") {
        set $customer $1;
        set $developer $2;
        set $rootpath "${developer}/${customer}/";
        set $servername "${customer}.${developer}.laravel";

        set $dynroot "$basepath/$rootpath/public";
    }

client_max_body_size 134M;

server_name "dev"

access_log "/home/nik/Code/App/nginx-logs/${servername}.access.log";

error_log "/home/nik/Code/App/nginx-logs/combined.error.log";

root $dynroot;

# check file exist and send request sting to index.php 
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    autoindex on;
}

# allow execute all php files
location ~ \.php$ {

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

# configure phpmyadmin path
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /usr/share/;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /usr/share/;
    }
}

location /phpMyAdmin {
    rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}

# disallow access to apache configs
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

# disallow access to git configs path
location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Comment: Change the `set $basepath "/home/nik/Code/";` to your windows code directory like `C:\\code`.

create a directory for logs `nginx-logs` in `C:\\Code`
access_log "C:\\code\nginx-logs\\${servername}.access.log";

error_log "C:\\code\nginx-logs\\nginx-logs\\combined.error.log";

Comment: this does not work. But what about the other parts such as the fastcgi_pass path or the $dynroot variable? I really do not know what to do with them..

Comment: Change the `$dynroot` value to `C:\\code` as well. for the `fastcgi_pass`  it will be in your php installation directory.